# code that will return the values from the list

Tags: python

If any values are entered in the list, they are printed.

If no value is entered in the list, it should print out `-1`

```
v = [13,26,27,29,59,62]

def search_list(v,n):
    if n ==v:
       print(n)
    else:
       print(-1)
print(search_list(v,13))
```

I wrote code like this. But the results are shown below

```
-1
None
```

Comment: Note: If your function does not return anything, python implicitly return `None`. Also use `for` loop to iterate one element at a time.

Comment: Also note that you compare an element to the entire list. You aren't checking if the v contains n. You're checking if v *is* n.

Comment: so your input cannot be negative? can it have more than 1 value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want `in` operator:

```
v = [13,26,27,29,59,62]

def search_list(v, n):
    if n in v:
       print(n)
    else:
       print(-1)
search_list(v, 13)
# 13
```

**Notes**:

- `in` operator checks if an item is in list or not.

*Usage*:

```
>>> v = [13,26,27,29,59,62]
>>> 13 in v
True
>>> 5 in v
False
```

- You don't require to `print(search_list(v, 13))` because the function
  does not return anything. By default if there is no return, Python
  returns a `None`. Hence you got a `None` at the end of your result.
  Just a call `search_list(v, 13)` should be enough. You are printing inside
  the function.

Answer (score 0):

As I see it you either want to search a list for a given value and then print it, then you can do it like that:

```
v = [13,26,27,29,59,62]

def search_list(v,n):
    if n in v:
       print(n)
    else:
       print(-1)
search_list(v,13)
```

no need to print it second time - you already did that in the function above, but if you want the function to return it instead, then just simply:

```
v = [13,26,27,29,59,62]

def search_list(v,n):
    if n in v:
       return n
    else:
       return -1
print(search_list(v,13))
```

Otherwise if you do

```
v = [13,26,27,29,59,62]

def search_list(v,n):
    if n in v:
       print(n)
    else:
       print(-1)
print(search_list(v,13))
```

The output will include `None` as you have not definied any return type, and so Python uses default, which is set to `None`

Answer (score 0):

You should use the in operator as against the equality operator like below.

`v = [13,26,27,29,59,62] 
def search_list(v, n): 
 if n in v: 
   print(n) 
 else: print(-1)
   search_list(v, 13) # 13`

In operator checks for presence of an item in the list, while the equality operator checks whether the single item is equal to the list which ll be always false.

Hope it helps